# How to grab a desktop screenshot with PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt

Can I take a screenshot from desktop or any window with PyQt? How to handle keyPressEvent on desktop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example of how to take a screenshot of the desktop:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId()).save('screenshot.jpg', 'jpg')
```

If you want to take a screenshot of a specific window, replace `QApplication.desktop()` with the widget you want to take a screenshot of.

Comment: Thank you. But how to handle keypress on desktop window?

Comment: That should be posted as a separate question.

Comment: HOw can we cat the window but not the whole screen?

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer. You pass a reference to a window instead of the desktop.

Comment: reference by name or reference by object? Just write it to your answer please.

Answer (score 1):

search the title items which you want

```
import win32gui
hwnd_title = dict()
def get_all_hwnd(hwnd,mouse):
  if win32gui.IsWindow(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
    hwnd_title.update({hwnd:win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)})

win32gui.EnumWindows(get_all_hwnd, 0)
 
for h,t in hwnd_title.items():
  if t is not "":
    print(h, t)
```

then use the title to screenshot

```
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
  from PyQt5.QtGui import *
  import win32gui
  import sys

  hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe')
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
  img = screen.grabWindow(hwnd).toImage()
  img.save("screenshot.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the App-Window use:

```
ex = Ui_MainWindow() #The class wher you call self.show()
QPixmap.grabWidget(ex).save('screenshot.jpg', 'jpg')
```